# How to set WPF's Grid.RowDefinitions via Style

Tags: wpf, grid, styles

I'm using a couple of `Grid`s to format multiple `GridViewColumn.CellTemplate`s:

```
<ListView SharedSizeScope="true">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="foo" />
                <!-- ... -->
```

I tried to extract the `RowDefinition`s (which are the same for all columns) into a `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
  <Setter Property="RowDefinitions">
    <Setter.Value>
      <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="foo" />
      <!-- ... -->
```

But the compiler complains:

> Error: The Property Setter
>   'RowDefinitions' cannot be set because
>   it does not have an accessible set
>   accessor.

Which is kind of obvious, but not very helpful.

How could I avoid specifying the row definitions multiple times (see also [Don't Repeat Yourself](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself)) short of coding up a custom derivation of the `Grid`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grid doesn't support control templates (info taken from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/731bf94e-0881-49e1-a35a-99a2e2ca647f/) and, indirectly, from [here](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/51448155-637c-469d-856b-ff81552fe980/)).